# marginpar in a macro steal the bullet of itemized list

Tags: macros, itemize, marginpar

I have an odd (to me) problem involving an itemize environment and `\marginpar{}`.  The problem is illustrated in the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\todo}[1]{\marginpar{\small\flushleft #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item first item
\item \todo{the second item is missing} third item
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I would have expected to get output resembling

- first item
- third item

together with a margin note saying "the second item is missing".  Instead I get the following:

[image: unexpected TeX output]

*i.e.* the black dot for the second bullet point somehow ended up in the margin!  The problem does not occur if I replace `\todo` with `\marginpar` in the itemized list, so the use of a macro is somehow part of this problem.

My questions:

1. What is going wrong here?
2. How can I fix my `\todo` macro to avoid this problem?

Comment: Don't use `\flushleft`. That starts a new list. Use `\raggedright`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is `\flushleft` which should be used as an environment. Use `\raggedright` instead which is a switch.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\todo}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedright\small#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item first item
\item \todo{the second item is missing} third item
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would prefer `marginnote` for better positioning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fulladjust]{marginnote}

\newcommand{\todo}[1]{\marginnote{\raggedright\small#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item first item
\item \todo{the second item is missing} third item
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This indeed fixes the problem, thanks!  It is still a mystery to me how the bullet made it into the margin, though; any ideas?  Probably something to do with some `\expandafter` deep in the guts of the definition of `\item`?

Comment: @jochen `\flushleft` starts a list again, that is why the bullet in the margin.